# Adding Custom URL Rewrites to Firebase Cloud Function for REST API

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am attempting to make my Firebase cloud function below available at a custom URL:

> https://example.com/myfancyredirected/orwhatever/

I have written the following Firebase Cloud Function to write data to my Cloud Firestore (extract of my index.js file):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./permissions.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "myDBlocation"
});

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = admin.firestore();

const cors = require('cors');
app.use( cors( {origin:true}));


//Create
let autoID = admin.database().ref().push().key;

app.post((req, res) => {
  
  (async() => {
   try
   {
      await db.collection('mycustomDBlocation').doc()
      .create({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description
      })

      return res.status(200).send('Received Thanks!');
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).send(error);
   }
  })();
  
});



exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I have also appended my firebase.json file with the following to re-write the location to a custom domain:

```
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/myfancyredirected/orwhatever/",
      "function": "app"
    } ]
```

The function works fine on the standard Firebase URL but not on the custom URL which is otherwise fully functioning and hosting a website through Firebase.

Any help on where I am going wrong would be appreciated?

Comment: Your `app.post()` doesn't specify a URL path.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @DougStevenson this was previously ```app.post('/myfancyredirected/orwhatever/', (req, res) => {``` which works for the standard cloudfunctions.net domain, but doesn't work on a custom domain / web.app URL

Comment: I think you're going to have to decide which one you want to use.  Make sure the path matches the actual request.

Comment: @MrT those path are defined on your front-end side i think cause this functions are used to make api calls and it is connected to your firebase project.

Comment: @DougStevenson when I declare my route in app.post as per my comment, the route isn't available on my custom domain, hence why I attempted to remove it as per my example above.

If I could figure out how to declare a route here whilst enabling it on my custom domain, then I would be happy.